# Recommended eCommerce Plugin for a T-Shirt Sales Business?

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, e-commerce

**I want to create a website for my T-Shirt business**. I've tried osCommerce and it's ok for a basic setup but even something simple as installing an addon for SEO turns into a nightmare of database editing and modifying php files.

I've used WordPress before and it's an absolute dream to setup and customise.

Here are the requirements that my shop would need:

1. **Multiple attibutes** - e.g. customer should be able to choose things like size, color, garment type etc. Also I need the option of an attibute to be able to change the price. E.g. If I have a base price of $11.99 and the cutomer selects "Kids small" for size then I want to deduct $3 from the base price.
2. **Display multiple pictures** depending on what I choose. E.g. if I choose a woman's tee from the garment type then the picture should update to display the design on a woman's tee.
3. **Bulk import/export** - I need to be able to mass import or export products, attributes etc. via something like CSV or Excel.
4. **Reporting tools would be nice**, so I can see my shops performance at a glance.

I know there are several eCommmerce plugins out there but do any of them do the things I've listed above?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Woo (the makers of WooThemes) announced their integration with shopify recently, from the looks of it... http://themes.shopify.com/themes/air/styles/air would do what you want..

I would look into hosting the shop at Shopify, and seeing if your base website can be wordpress. Woo has announced that they're working on a e-commerce framework as well, but until that gets released, this may work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Use WP e-Commerce Plugin from GetShopped.org and if it doesnt do exactly what you want straight away then you can commission somebody to do the rest.

Woo are making a Plugin but its going to be years behind (in terms of features) compared to WP e-Commerce, Shopp, Yak etc...

Answer (score 1):

I've used [WP e-Commerce](http://www.instinct.co.nz/e-commerce/) to great success.  It's very expandable, the presentation layer is easy to customize.  It handles most basic features out of the box.  You may have to use a DIY option for csv import/export.

Answer (score 1):

I like the plugin Shopp, great ressource and you create custom shops in custom design. Also you have hooks for hook inside the shopp for custom functions: http://shopplugin.net/